# which cpu is targeted with gcc's -mtune=generic?

Tags: gcc

With gcc, you can specify "-mtune=" or "-mtune=generic"

How can I know which architecture is targeted with "-mtune=generic" for gcc?  It's supposed to be varying based on different versions of GCC?

The docs https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options say:

`As new processors are deployed in the marketplace, the behavior of this option will change. Therefore, if you upgrade to a newer version of GCC, code generation controlled by this option will change to reflect the processors that are most common at the time that version of GCC is released.`

How can I know which one each version of GCC targets?

The docs say:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options

```
...
‘i686’
When used with -march, the Pentium Pro instruction set is used, 
so the code runs on all i686 family chips. When used with -mtune, it has the same meaning as ‘generic’.
```

So I guess generic "means" i686 but is that a particular CPU?

Comment: You may try adding `-fverbose-asm -S` and check first lines of generated asm for options... Do you want to know mtune=generic of x86/x86_64 or of any gcc-supported arch?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily target one specific cpu. It can be a compromise, avoiding code that would be horribly slow on some amd cpu, avoiding other code that would be horribly slow on some intel cpu, endinp up with something that is not optimal for any cpu but still ok everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know which architecture is targeted with "-mtune=generic" for gcc?

By reading the true documentation, the source code of gcc (search for `PROCESSOR_GENERIC` after `switch(tune)`:

For x86 (32/64 bit) [gcc/config/i386/i386-c.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/edd716b6b1caa1a5cb320a8cd7f626f30198e098/gcc/config/i386/i386-c.c) it will not define builtins/arch macro,

```
  /* Built-ins based on -mtune=.  */
  switch (tune)

    case PROCESSOR_GENERIC:
      break;
```

and [gcc/config/i386/driver-i386.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/7440da4555dde514c97ea5c8fa32e7b7b3640cc2/gcc/config/i386/driver-i386.c) will not detect local cpu with cpuid (`host_detect_local_cpu` will not be called without `cpu=native` / `tune=native`

You may try adding `-fverbose-asm -S` and check first lines of generated asm for options..